# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/microposts/304 - Deleting a Micropost - Michael Hartl's railstutorial.org Chapter 11

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org.  I'm having trouble with Chapter 11, specifically when attempting to delete a micropost.

I'm having the same problem as this user [Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/microposts/304"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871875/no-route-matches-error-on-delete-of-micropost-in-chapter-11-of-hartls-ruby-on).  He was able to solve the problem by commenting out the jQuery gem and it worked.  I, however, wasn't as lucky.

Here is my current Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'

group :development do
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
#group :assets do
#  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
#  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
#end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

=> A quick side-note: An error [No Javascript runtime on windows when running rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047651/no-javascript-runtime-on-windows-when-running-rails-server) kept arising when I ran the `rails server` command but once I commented out the `'sass-rails'`, `'coffee-rails'`, and `'uglifier'` gems it would run successfully.  I'm using a Windows PC and was told that this might be a specific problem to Windows machines.

Also, here is the current outcome of my `bundle install` command:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using multi_json (1.0.3)
Using activesupport (3.1.1)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using activemodel (3.1.1)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.3.5)
Using rack-cache (1.1)
Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.0.3)
Using actionpack (3.1.1)
Using mime-types (1.17.2)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.3.0)
Using actionmailer (3.1.1)
Using arel (2.2.1)
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
Using activerecord (3.1.1)
Using activeresource (3.1.1)
Using ansi (1.4.1)
Using bundler (1.0.21)
Using faker (0.3.1)
Using gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0.pre2)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.6.1)
Using rdoc (3.11)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.1.1)
Using jquery-rails (1.0.17)
Using pg (0.11.0)
Using rails (3.1.1)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.4)
Using turn (0.8.3)
Using will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.  **Is there a specific gem that I need to install in order for the delete method to work?**  I appreciate your help!

Here is the `rake routes` output:

```
(in C:/rails_projects/sample_app)
      users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"us
ers"}
            POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"u
sers"}
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"user
s"}
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"use
rs"}
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"use
rs"}
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"u
sers"}
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"
users"}
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"s
essions"}
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sess
ions"}
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"
sessions"}
 microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"m
icroposts"}
  micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"
microposts"}
     signup        /signup(.:format)         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"ne
w"}
     signin        /signin(.:format)         {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>
"new"}
    signout        /signout(.:format)        {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>
"destroy"}
    contact        /contact(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"co
ntact"}
      about        /about(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"ab
out"}
       help        /help(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"he
lp"}
       root        /                         {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"ho
me"}
```

Here is a partial view file using the delete method:

```
<tr>
  <td class="micropost">
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </td>
  <% user = micropost.user rescue User.find(micropost.user_id) %>
  <% if current_user?(user) %>
  <td>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, :method => :delete,
                                     :confirm => "You sure?",
                                     :title => micropost.content %>
  </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Again, the source code can be viewed on Github https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app, it just seems to not be running properly on my machine which leads me to believe it is something along the lines as this [user's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871875/no-route-matches-error-on-delete-of-micropost-in-chapter-11-of-hartls-ruby-on) problem.

Comment: What's your output for `rake routes`?

Comment: Also, what is the view code you're using to output the link/button/whatever that deletes the post?

Comment: @sarnold: I was using rake 0.9.2 and running `rake routes` didn't work.  So, I followed this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl> example and switched to rake 0.8.7 and `rake routes` worked.  I appended it to the question.

Comment: @BrandonTilley:  I added the view partial which is calling the delete function.  Let me know if you need other files.  Thanks for you time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524693/1092806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing one of these two.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I accidentally removed  //= require jquery_ujs and this gave me the same problem.

Comment: I made the same mistake, saw your pointer here and voila! Problem solved!

Comment: @NickLewis nice, i could help. can you please vote my answer up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using both prototype and jquery in your app?
I can see that you are using jquery-rails gem, but is the prototype also present there?
Check if both are being loaded, as they clash with each other.

Comment: I tried switching the microposts_controller method to `delete`, didn't work.  Then I tried switching the views to `:destroy`, didn't work.  Hmm...

Comment: I installed `gem 'prototype-rails' '3.1.0'`, but the delete function didn't work - it gave me the same error message.  I then commented out the jQuery gem and tried running it again but still no success.  Do you think it has to do with the error message I received when attempting to do the `rails server` command early in development stating, ["Could not find a Javascript runtime."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047651/no-javascript-runtime-on-windows-when-running-rails-server)?